# C# HttpContext request internal Kubernetes URLs

Tags: c#, .net, kubernetes, .net-core, reverse-proxy

When I try to send requests to internal Kubernetes services I get:

> Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

because the URL is not a standard example.com URL. How can I use HttpClient to successfully send these requests?

Comment: What does your Kubernetes URL look like?
I'm assuming something like `http://my-service-name.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local:8080/test`?

Comment: @LeviFuller base url looks like this: `myservicename-svc.service-svc`

Answer (score 2):

I just needed to add `http(s)://` to the URL